# How to make GCC enforce pure/const attribute?

Tags: gcc, constants

I tried using attribute const and pure to try to make GCC enforce that a function is not allowed to access any global variables but this compiles just fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int data;

__attribute__((const))
int test_func(int val){
    data = val;
    return data;
}

int main(){
    scanf("%d", &data);
    printf("test: %d\n", test_func(data));
    return 0;
}
```

This should not compile.

Is there a way to enforce the rule that neither the function itself nor any other functions it calls can access any variables besides their arguments?

Answer (score 2):

[GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) says that `__attribute__((const))` is used by the programmer to indicate the behavior of the function so that it can be optimized better.

> Calls to functions whose return value is not affected by changes to the observable state of the program and that have no observable effects on such state other than to return a value may lend themselves to optimizations such as common subexpression elimination. Declaring such functions with the const attribute allows GCC to avoid emitting some calls in repeated invocations of the function with the same argument values.

In the documentation there are some cases for which a compile error is promised, and wrong behavior (accessing globals within the function) is not one of those. Therefore you are responsible to not use this attribute for functions that use globals.

Comment: Do you know if there is any other way to bar access to global state for the whole call tree?

Comment: @Martin, move the call tree to another file and not export global state there?

Comment: No there shouldn't be any global state. Ideally it would be best to have two enforcing levels from compiler. One that disallows access to variables outside of the function arguments but allows pointer access and another that only allows parameters to be passed by value. Naturally any functions that are called by a pure method must be pure as well. It would even be nice to bar access to variables outside of the parameter list by default and have an attribute that allows it instead.

Comment: For now I will probably just enforce it using nm and dump of global variables that would be checked as part of test suite and should never increase in size. But it would be better I think to enforce this at compiler level.

Comment: This makes this attribute so useless.